# Is there any way to get rid of "frozen" box on screen without closing the program?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

Sometimes, a program shows tooltips or dialogs or some other things but the region where they were displayed never disappear unless the program is quitted. See the pictures for examples.

I'm using Gnome and Ubuntu 16.04. But I also met such situations on other environments.

[image]

[image]